# How can I get "Search Queries" data from Google WMT?

Tags: c#, .net, service, google-search-console

I'm triyng to get data from the Search Queries section in Google WMT. I'm using a simple console app in C# .net 4.5. Thanks to [this source,](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-WebMasterTools/Google-WebmasterTools-dotnet) I instanciated the connexion but now I have a service which I can't use as I want.

Here is my working code for now, which get my websites :

```
var service = Authentication.AuthenticateOauth(client_id, client_secret, user);

        if (DaimtoWebMasterSitesHelper.list(service).SiteEntry != null)
        {
            foreach (var site in DaimtoWebMasterSitesHelper.list(service).SiteEntry)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Site: " + site.SiteUrl);

            }
        }
```

I would like to get "CTR", "Impressions" and "Clicks" for web & mobile but I have no idea how to ... I'm stuck with this for way too much time, I was happy this morning when I found this piece of code but now i'm stuck again ...

In fact my question is: Is it even possible ?

Can someone help me ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Search Queries API is currently in limited mode, meaning we're (Google) testing it with people who showed interest and subscribed when we announced we'll launch it in limited beta. Once testing is done, we'll very likely launch it for the general public, but I don't have a timeframe for that.

You can find the currently supported methods and more information about them in the [API Explorer for Search Console (former Webmaster Tools)](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/)
For `webmasters.searchanalytics.query` it currently says:

> [LIMITED ACCESS] Query your data with filters and parameters that you define. Returns zero or more rows grouped by the row keys that you define. You must define a date range of one or more days. When date is one of the group by values, any days without data are omitted from the result list. If you need to know which days have data, issue a broad date range query grouped by date for any metric, and see which day rows are returned.