# “Search Queries” data from Google WMT

Tags: perl, perl-module, google-search-console

I want to get the key words (aka "`queries`") that are used by users to find a webpage on google. The same keywords that are shown in Google Analytics. I want to get them using the API ([Search Console / Webmaster Tool API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query)). As mentioned in the accepted answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270098/how-can-i-get-search-queries-data-from-google-wmt) there was a time when this part of the Google WebMaster tools API was not available to public.

I was wondering if this is still valid because I found no official google page which says so. Nevertheless I was not able to retrieve data from the API.

I tried to code a script (using Perl with [Net::Google::WebmasterTools](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::WebmasterTools)). I was able to authorize and send a request. I also got a reply with status 200 but containing no data (especially no keywords, which is what I want to get). Nevertheless, I can see the keywords when browsing to the Search WebmasterTools Analytics Report.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::Google::WebmasterTools;
use Net::Google::WebmasterTools::OAuth2;
use Data::Dumper;
use URL::Encode 'url_encode';

my $site_url      = url_encode("http://www.example.com");
my $client_id     = "[ID]";
my $client_secret = "[SECRET]";
my $refresh_token = "[TOKEN]";

my $wmt = Net::Google::WebmasterTools->new;

my $oauth = Net::Google::WebmasterTools::OAuth2->new(
    client_id     => $client_id,
    client_secret => $client_secret,
);

my $token = $oauth->refresh_access_token($refresh_token);
print Dumper($token);

$wmt->token($token);

# Build request
my $req = $wmt->new_request(
    site_url            => "$site_url",
    report_name         => "searchAnalytics",
    method              => "query",
    dimensions          => ['Country','Device','Query'],
    #search_type        => 'web',
    start_date          => '2015-01-01',
    end_date            => '2015-09-30',
    row_limit           => 1000,
);
print $req;
# Send request
my $res = $wmt->retrieve($req);
die("GWMT error: " . $res->error_message) if !$res->is_success;
# Print results

print Dumper($res);

print
    "Results: 1 - ", $res->items_per_page,
    " of ", $res->total_results, "\n\n";

for my $row (@{ $res->rows }) {
    print
        $row->get_source,  ": ",
        $row->get_visits,  " visits, ",
        $row->get_bounces, " bounces\n";
}

print
    "\nTotal: ",
    $res->totals("visits"),  " visits, ",
    $res->totals("bounces"), " bounces\n";
```

I also tried using the API Explorer for `webmasters.searchanalytics.query` but as response I get `500 Internal Server Error`.

I'm not sure if I use the api in a wrong way or if it is still not supported. Does anyone have "recent" experience about that? (maybe by using another programming language or library).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get "Search Queries" data from Google WMT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270098/how-can-i-get-search-queries-data-from-google-wmt)

Comment: I wrote there. But I was recommended to post this as a new question. So I did.

Comment: Its the same question with the same answer there for its a duplicate only difference is the language sorry.

Comment: In my opinion the question of the person in the duplicate was like "why is it not working". And the answer was like "its not supported yet". In contrast, my question was related to the answer of the other question like "Is this answer still valid, is it still not supported by google or is it?".

Comment: @user3215297: Your post there was off-topic. Stack Overflow isn't a forum, and you should only ever offer answers or comments that support the original question. That said, there is nothing wrong with a *new* question that says *"I'm using Perl instead of C sharp but the answers to this old question don't work for me"*. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ok, I understand the off-topic-thing now. Yes thats what I'm asking. Although I would not stick on the programming language because it doesn't matter if it is still not supported / working (in any language) at all.

Comment: as far I know and as far as i can tell from digging around in the documentation and testing it its still not supported.   I don't think that Google is going to give you keyword info via any API for the same reasons it was removed from Google Analytics.

Comment: @DaImTo: Are u sure? I found docs where it seems like it should work. Because it say you can use dimensionFilterGroups[].filters[].dimensions with "query" to filter against the specified query string. I thought this would be exactly those keywords. See https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query#dimensionFilterGroups.filters.dimension But they may just have forgotten to update this part of the docs. i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is fully operational.

Try  ['country','device','query'] instead of the propercase equivalents.

...and the docs are wrong regarding paging -- it DOES support paging, but there is a caveat: stop when a page contains less than 5000 rows. Also you will have to deduplicate between pages since the output is sorted only on the 'clicks' column and below that is randomly/inconsistently sorted, which means you can get the same row in multiple pages if the page-break occurs when there are 2 or more rows with that number of clicks (particularly bad with 0 click rows).

Comment: You are right, the api is working as expected. however 'country' instead of 'Country' was not the important thing. The problem was that I used a date (range) more than a year ago, where no data was available. I replaced 2015 with 2016 for start_date and end_date and its working as expected now.